# Convert unicode to string in python

Tags: python-3.x, unicode

How can i convert unicode characters into text? Preferably without importing any library. Input is a string from a list.
Sample input:

```
\\u006A\\u0061\\u0064\\u0072\\u006F
```

expected output:

```
jadro
```

(+ should not be a bytes class at the end)
a list i am translating:

```
["I[0][1][0][0] = '\\u006A\\u0061\\u0064\\u0072\\u006F';", "I[1][1][0][0] = '\\u0047\\u0075\\u0074\\u0065\\u006E\\u0062\\u0065\\u0072\\u0067\\u006F\\u0076\\u0061';", "I[2][1][0][0] = '\\u0070\\u006C\\u00E1\\u0161\\u0165';", "I[3][1][0][0] = '\\u0061\\u0073\\u0074\\u0065\\u006E\\u006F\\u0073\\u0066\\u00E9\\u0072\\u0061';", "I[4][1][0][0] = '\\u004D\\u006F\\u0068\\u006F\\u0072\\u006F\\u0076\\u0069\\u010D\\u0069\\u010D\\u006F\\u0076\\u0061';", "I[5][1][0][0] = '\\u006B\\u00F4\\u0072\\u0061';", "I[6][1][0][0] = '\\u0050\\u0065\\u0076\\u006E\\u0069\\u006E\\u0073\\u006B\\u00E1';", "I[7][1][0][0] = '\\u0067\\u0072\\u0061\\u006E\\u0069\\u0074\\u006F\\u0076\\u00E1';", "I[8][1][0][0] = '\\u0034\\u002C\\u0035';", "I[9][1][0][0] = '\\u0070\\u0072\\u0076\\u006F\\u0068\\u00F4\\u0072';", "I[10][1][0][0] = '\\u0052\\u006F\\u0064\\u0069\\u006E\\u0069\\u0061';", "I[11][1][0][0] = '\\u0050\\u0061\\u006E\\u0067\\u0065\\u0061';", "I[12][1][0][0] = '\\u0065\\u0075\\u0072\\u00E1\\u007A\\u0069\\u006A\\u0073\\u006B\\u00E1';", "I[13][1][0][0] = '\\u0070\\u0061\\u0063\\u0069\\u0066\\u0069\\u0063\\u006B\\u00E1';", "I[14][1][0][0] = '\\u0041\\u0074\\u006C\\u0061\\u006E\\u0074\\u0069\\u0063\\u006B\\u00E1';", "I[15][1][0][0] = '\\u0069\\u006E\\u0064\\u006F';", "I[16][1][0][0] = '\\u0061\\u0066\\u0072\\u0069\\u0063\\u006B\\u00E1';", "I[17][1][0][0] = '\\u0061\\u006E\\u0074\\u0061\\u0072\\u006B\\u0074\\u0069\\u0063\\u006B\\u00E1';", "I[18][1][0][0] = '\\u0076\\u0072\\u00E1\\u0073\\u006E\\u0065\\u006E\\u0069\\u0065';", "I[19][1][0][0] = '\\u0068\\u0072\\u0061\\u0073\\u0165';", "I[20][1][0][0] = '\\u0070\\u0072\\u0069\\u0065\\u006B\\u006F\\u0070\\u006F\\u0076\\u00E1\\u0020\\u0070\\u0072\\u0065\\u0070\\u0061\\u0064\\u006C\\u0069\\u006E\\u0061';", "I[21][1][0][0] = '\\u006D\\u0061\\u0067\\u006D\\u0061\\u0074\\u0069\\u0063\\u006B\\u00FD\\u0020\\u006B\\u0072\\u0062';", "I[22][1][0][0] = '\\u004B\\u0061\\u006C\\u0064\\u0065\\u0072\\u0061';", "I[23][1][0][0] = '\\u0056\\u0065\\u007A\\u0075\\u0076';", "I[24][1][0][0] = '\\u0048\\u0061\\u0076\\u0061\\u006A\\u0073\\u006B\\u00FD\\u0063\\u0068';", "I[25][1][0][0] = '\\u0046\\u0075\\u0064\\u017E\\u0069';", "I[26][1][0][0] = '\\u006B\\u0079\\u0073\\u006C\\u00E9';", "I[27][1][0][0] = '\\u0062\\u0061\\u007A\\u0061\\u006C\\u0074\\u0069\\u0063\\u006B\\u00E1';", "I[28][1][0][0] = '\\u0052\\u0069\\u0063\\u0068\\u0074\\u0065\\u0072\\u006F\\u0076\\u006F\\u0075';", "I[29][1][0][0] = '\\u0073\\u0065\\u0069\\u007A\\u006D\\u006F\\u0067\\u0072\\u0061\\u0066';"]
```

code for saving the translated and crrupted result:

```
f = open("dump.TXT","w+")
f.close()
f = open("dump.TXT","a")
for i in res:
    unic = i.split("'")[-2]
    trans = bytes(unic,"utf-8").decode('unicode-escape') + "\n"
    trans = trans.encode('utf-8').decode('utf8')
    f.write(trans)
```

Full code:

```
import re

with open("org22.htm","r") as f:
    data = f.read()

start = "I = new Array();"
end = "State = new Array();"
s = data
array_r = s[s.find(start)+len(start):s.rfind(end)]
array_r = array_r.split("\n")
count, res = 0, []
for line in array_r:
    compare = "I["+str(count)+"][1][0][0] ="
    if compare in line:
            res.append(line)
            count += 1

f = open("dump.TXT","w+")
f.close()
f = open("dump.TXT","a")
for i in res:
    unic = i.split("'")[-2]
    trans = bytes(unic,"utf-8").decode('unicode-escape') + "\n"
    trans = trans.encode('utf-8').decode('utf8')
    f.write(trans)

f.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear if your input is bytes or a string. If it's a string, you can convert to bytes and decode with `unicode-escape`:

```
s = "\\u006A\\u0061\\u0064\\u0072\\u006F"

bytes(s, 'utf-8').decode('unicode-escape')
# 'jadro'
```

If it's already bytes, then just:

```
b = b"\\u006A\\u0061\\u0064\\u0072\\u006F"

b.decode('unicode-escape')
```

Comment: Hi, now it produces this: kysl� instead of this: kyslá, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @peter123 what are you starting with that is supposed to produce `kyslá`?

Comment: the problem is that it is supposed to save: kyslá, and different words with special characters but corrupts them

Comment: The code you provided works but i am translating a list

Comment: Ill add the list to the question

Comment: @peter123 I'm not sure what's going on. The text you sent is translating fine for me — even text like `plášť`. Maybe you need to provide the encoding when you open the file? Also, maybe you are reading from a non-utf-8 file and then trying to append to it. Try writing to a new file.

Comment: I did @peter123 — I think the issue is that you are appending to a non-utf-8 file `dump.TXT`. I get bad characters if I do that.

Comment: Or it may be that vs-code doesnt recognise those characters...

Comment: I can see the characters fine in VS code. In VS-code look at the bottom of the window and see if you can tell what the encoding it.

Comment: Utf-8 but i added tge full code + here is the file its opening: https://anonfile.com/p9N4E3y7o2/org22_htm

Comment: Wow it was actually just vscode, in notepad its fine :D . Anyways a huge thanks for your help and time :)